# Swipe left and right between Core Data with a label

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I hope you can help. 
There is a label and when any user swipe on it. It will make a call to core data and show values on label. Data will depend upon gesture. If its left/right data will be different on each time. Below is the code that i have written. Please suggest whether its correct or not?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var helloArray = [Tasks]()
    var currentArrayIndex = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleSwipes(sender:)))

        leftSwipe.direction = .left
        rightSwipe.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        ouputData()
    }

    @objc func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.direction == .left {
            currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + 1) % 3
        }
    }

    func ouputData() {
        do {
            helloArray = try context.fetch(Tasks.fetchRequest())
            for each in helloArray {
                helloLabel.text = each.name
            }
        } catch {
        }
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }

    @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let infoTasks = Tasks(context: context)
        infoTasks.name = textField.text

        appDelegate.saveContext()

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
        textField.text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want to do on btnPressed.?

Comment: btnPressed is there so it saves core data. I put an input into a textfield and when i press the button it saves to core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to modify your handleSwipes and outputData function.

You outputData should only fetch all the data from CD in viewDidload.
Once you have the data source you can fetch item from source and populate your helloLabel based on index.

```
@objc func handleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.direction == .left {
            currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex + 1) % 3
        } else if sender.direction == .right {
            currentArrayIndex = (currentArrayIndex - 1) % 3
        }
        helloLabel.text =  helloArray[currentArrayIndex].name
    }
```

And:

```
func ouputData() {
        do {
            helloArray = try context.fetch(Tasks.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
        }
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, with the helloArray[currentArrayIndex] I keep getting an error "Cannot assign value of type 'Tasks' to type 'String?'" I can't figure out how to stop it.

Comment: sorry 4 that. I have modified the code actually it should be helloLabel.text =  helloArray[currentArrayIndex].name. since helloArray[currentArrayIndex] will return task and you need to get name from task.

Comment: Thank you so much that works, just another quick one if you don't mind, when swiping it doesn't show the third and fourth CD inputs etc?

Comment: probably you need to check the datasource - which is in this case helloArray - you can print it and see what are the data it contains. my guess is it having nothing - an empty data